# Using send API of gupshup to reply to a user within 24 hrs shows an User not opted-in error

Tags: gupshup

I have my own bot running locally and have made it publicly accessible using ngrok

Trying to use the sandbox environment of gupshup to communicate with my bot.

Have hooked my bot using webhook (link your bot)

Have also created a BOT and configured the webhook as a callback POST to my ngrok server.

However when i try replying to a user supplied whats app message after say about 10 min using the Delayed response strategy i.e. by passing the contextobj and message via the send API ([http://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/bot/{botname}/msg](http://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/bot/%7Bbotname%7D/msg)), I get an error stating "User Not Opted In".

Why isnt the user considered as an Active User since the messaging was initiated by the user and the send API is only replying to that message with 24 hrs ?

How do i simply give a delayed response to the user within 24hrs without forcing the user to opt-in ?

Answer (score 0):

We do this all the time, however we are using the endpoint documented here:

https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/whatsapp-api-documentation#OutboundMessage

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the consent of user once before sending messages.
Also while using sandbox the user needs to opt in but for verified user it will be relaxed.
But still you will need to take consent of user at any place (your site, your terms and conditions or anywhere) before sending him anything for the record purposes so that they cannot claim that you are spamming them without consent.